# Ski Lift - Expectation Value

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

The following is an exercise from my textbook.

> Let $Y$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be independent copies of $Y$. Further let $X$ be a markov chain with $X_0$ independent from $Y_i$ and recursive defined by
>   $$
>   X_{n+1} = \max{(X_n -1,0) + Y_{n+1}}
> $$

Interpretation: $Y_{n+1}$ new skier arrive at the ski-lift between the timepoints in which the $n$-th and $(n+1)$-th Person is being transported. Hence, $X_{n}$ would be the length of the queue after which $n$ persons are transported.

I was able to calculate the transition matrix but I'm stuck with the following (and clueless especially with the second one):

How can I show that $0$ is recurrent, if $\mathbb{E}{[Y]} \leq 1$
and that $0$ is transience, if $\mathbb{E}{[Y]} > 1$?

Comment: Which tools do you know to show recurrence or transience?

Comment: Some indication of the transition matrix you found should be given, so Readers can start with your previous work.  Posting mathematical expressions, including matrices, is outlined here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).